# How to calculate ACF from PACF?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I have tried to search a lot on Google but could not find any information regarding the relationship between ACF and PACF.

Say I have PACF at lag 1, 2, and 3. How could I calculate the ACF for lag 1, 2, 3 respectively?

Thanks

Comment: My gut feeling is that you can't. You calculate or estimate both based on the original time series, but you can't go from one to the other directly in general. (If you assume a specific model, e.g., AR($p$), and have "enough" values of the ACF/PACF, you can probably recover the coefficients of the original model using the Yule-Walker equation and do what you want.) Are you looking to translate the abstract equations, or to "translate" *estimated* ACF/PACF back and forth?